# Make with files that must be edited manually

Tags: makefile

I'm writing some Makefile.  There is a file `auto` that can be processed in automatic way (build by `make`).  There is recipe for it.  So, this file needs to be edited manually and saved as `manual`.  This `manual` is used for further automatic processing.  How can I achieve the next:

1. If `auto` is not exists --- build it --- done by the recipe for it.
2. If `manual` is older than `auto` --- print a message and exit `make`.
3. If `manual` is newer --- build further --- done by the recipe for it.

How can the second step be done in some native way?

**EDIT**

The process description was not clear enough because I had no understanding how it should be. That was my mistake.  Here is the process I assume.

1. There is `source`.
2. The `auto` can be built automatically from `source`.
3. The `manual` can be made manually from `auto`.
4. The `result` can be built automatically from `manual`.

Going 1->2 and 3->4 is what is `make` for.

The `manual` depends on `source`.  But `make` itself can't build `manual` but only `auto` to help the user.  So, if the `manual` is up-to-date (newer than `source`), then just build `result` from it.

But if `manual` is have to be rebuilt (it is older than `source`), rebuild `auto` (if needed), print a message and stop.

So, I think that `Makefile` should looks like:

```
SOURCE = source

result : manual ; cp manual result

manual : auto $(SOURCE) ; @echo "CREATE $@"

auto : $(SOURCE) ; cp source auto
```

But making `result` I have to stop after `manual` and let user to create it and run `make` again.  The `manual` will be newer than `source` and `auto` and will not have to be rebuilt.  But how can I do this?

Comment: As you have two files involved there are 5 base cases: a) none exist, b) only `manual` exists, c) only `auto` exists, d) both exist and `auto` is older, e) both exist and `manual` is older. Your rule 1 specifies what to do in cases a) and b). Rule 2 specifies what to do in case e). Rule 3 specifies what to do in case d). What about case c)? And you also forgot to explain a bit more the recipe for `auto`. Is it the same recipe that builds `auto` when it does not exist and when it exists but `manual` is newer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to describe your dependencies as they really are, even if you cannot really build `manual` with a make recipe. Then, for `manual`, instead of writing a building recipe, just print your message and exit with a non-zero status. If `manual`does not exist or is out of date, make will print the message and stop before trying to (re)build `result`:

```
# Makefile
result: manual
    cp -f "$<" "$@"

manual: auto
    @echo "CREATE $@"
    @exit 1

auto: source
    cp -f "$<" "$@"
```

Demo:

```sh
$ rm -f auto manual result source
$ touch source
$ make
cp -f "source" "auto"
CREATE manual
make: *** [Makefile:6: manual] Error 1
$ touch manual
$ make
cp -f "manual" "result"
$ make
make: 'result' is up to date.
$ touch source
$ make
cp -f "source" "auto"
CREATE manual
make: *** [Makefile:6: manual] Error 1
```

If you don't like the error situation you can defer the stop to the `result` recipe:

```
# Makefile
result: manual
    [ -f "$@" ] && cp -f "$<" "$@" || true

manual: auto
    @echo "CREATE $@"

auto: source
    cp -f "$<" "$@"
```

Demo:

```sh
$ rm -f auto manual result source
$ touch source
$ make
cp -f "source" "auto"
CREATE manual
[ -f "manual" ] && cp -f "manual" "result" || true
$ touch manual
$ make
[ -f "manual" ] && cp -f "manual" "result" || true
$ make
make: 'result' is up to date.
$ touch source
$ make
cp -f "source" "auto"
CREATE manual
$ make
CREATE manual
$ touch manual
$ make
[ -f "manual" ] && cp -f "manual" "result" || true
```